# Appending multiple values for a key

Tags: python

```
if filename not in dict1.keys():
    dict1[filename] = {}
if transId not in dict1[filename].keys():
    dict1[filename][transId] = {}
if error_type in dict1[filename][transId].keys():
    count1 = dict1[filename][transId][error_type]
    count1 = count1 + 1
    dict1[filename][transId][error_type] = count1
```

dict data is :

```
{'abc': {'ACE12345678': {'ERR-2': 2}, {'ERR-3': 4}}}
```

where 'abc' is a filename, 'ACE12345678' a TransId, and 'ERR-2' an Error Type.

I would also like to add loglines for each transid(Eg: 'ACE12345678') so that the dict looks like as below :

```
{'abc': {'ACE12345678': {'ERR-2': 2, data1\n data2\n data3\n}, {'ERR-3': 4, data1\n data2\n data3\n}}}.
```

Can someone help me getting this output.

Comment: can you post your dict data ?

Comment: what's your purpose? maybe there's other way to replace this kind of weird practices.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a new key `loglines` that holds all the lines in a list:

```
dict1 = {'abc': {'ACE12345678': {'ERR-2': 2}}}
filename = 'abc'
transID = 'ACE12345678'
error_type = 'ERR-2'
logline = 'data1\n'


my_error = dict1.setdefault(filename, {}).setdefault(transID, {})
my_error[error_type] =  my_error.get(error_type, 0) + 1
my_error.setdefault('loglines', []).append(logline) 

print(dict1)
```

output:

```
{'abc': {'ACE12345678': {'ERR-2': 3, 'loglines': ['data1\n']}}}
```